# Consuming webservice from SABA

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services, soap

I need to customize a SABA page in order to add an HTML button on a special rendered page.
Pressing the button a web service must be called to get an answer according to input parameters and so take an appropriate action.

The WS accept as input a JSON variable like:
{
"check": int,
"planTitle":"..."
}

After invoking the WS (ie: calling it at uri like: http://www.blablabla.com:8080/resource/services/service1
I will get a JSON variable with the results.

The classical soap envelop returned by the server is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:getInfoResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.blablabla.com/">{"check":1,......}</ns1:getInfoResponse>
```

Consider also that The Saba server and webservice server could be hosted on different machines but on the same intranet.

Now, I have two possible solutions:

1. Implement a webservice in java on the server.......but I cannot understand the simplicity or the validity of such effort.....(the client side?)
2. Use Jquery or directly Javascript to call the webservice directly in the HTML rendered page and obtain the result on the fly
   with a lot of elegant and simplicity. The only question resides on possible Cross Browser problems or others also based on the SABA SW restrictions,
   but I image on the intranet, for instance, the cross browser aspect can be overcome.

So which solution You could suggest me and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time and without any help i solved the problem by myself. So i wish to share with all of you the approach used.

To consume a web service from the client side with jQuery at the moment the Remy Blom plugin  (refers to: http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/)
can be considered a valid alternative, enough valid so that it does the job for you as simple as possible.
This plugin must be improved again but it's very easy to use. It's based, of course, on the ajax callback.
So how you can imagine, if there is no possibility to manage the server side configuration to allow "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and mainly
if we need to connect from internet to an intranet webservice server we need to enlarge our horizons.

According to my experience the best and simple way to solve such a situation could be:

1. writing a server side web service to proxy the request and return the result
2. writing a server side proxy page

I love to write a simple and minimal server side web page simply to consume the web service and return the answer to the calling.
The parameters must be passed to such a page via a post/get call and the resulting page must contains an appropriate field to contain the result.

Why I prefer to do so? 
Because, with minimal lines of code on server side i can also offer to the customer the possibility to test if the call to WS runs correctly 
with some parameters decided on the fly by the customer and looking to the html page on the browser for the result.

For me it's the right compromise to create a proxy on the server side, to use it by the client side and to let the customer to test it by himself.

Security problems? Oh no. They are completely up to the security of the web server where you add the proxy page.

This solution also is enough flexible to be used with: java, c#, nodejs, php, perl,......

So it's absolutely not important which kind of web server i have: some times the only word Saba can make confusing.

Let's describe the solution.

On the server side I created a simple Saba web page mainly containg the following server code in order to get input parameters from the request, 
build the web service call and consume it. With the result an output field is fulfilled.
The Java code (using axis 1) is:

```
    try {
    if (wsEndPoint == null || wsEndPoint.trim().length() == 0 || wsNAME == null || wsNAME.trim().length() == 0 ||
        id == null || id.trim().length() == 0 || code == null || code.trim().length() == 0) {
        retVal = "Error: mandatory parameter missing.";
    } else {
        Service  service = new Service();
        Call call = (Call)service.createCall();

        call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(wsEndPoint));
        call.setOperationName(new QName("http://service.name.it/", wsNAME));
        call.addParameter(new QName("http://service.name.it/", "arg0"), new QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"), ParameterMode.IN);
        call.addParameter(new QName("http://service.name.it/", "arg1"), new QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"), ParameterMode.IN);
        call.setSOAPActionURI("");
        call.setEncodingStyle(null);
        call.setProperty(Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
        call.setProperty(AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);

        retVal = ((String)call.invoke(new Object[] {id, code})).trim();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    retVal = String.format("Error: %s.", e.getMessage());
```

}

The core of corresponding client side page referring to the previous code is:

```
    <form method="POST" name="myform">
    <table border="0" width="75%">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Web Service proxy page</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>ws End Point</td>
           <td><input name="wsEndPoint" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ws Function Name</td>
          <td><input name="wsNAME" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><ID</td>
          <td><input name="ID" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>code</td>
          <td><input name="CODE" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>return Value</td>
          <td><input name="retVal" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
</form>
```

Now, to test the page is simply required to open in the browser a link like:

```
http://localhost/myproxypage?ID=312001&CODE=CV2W1-OF00MA&wsEndPoint=http:%2F%2Ffedora:9000%2Faxis%2Fservices%2FwsInfo&wsNAME=mywsname
```

If the customer is far from you, you could send the page to him and ask to run the previous link with the arguments he wishes and reads the result field.
That can help you to complete this part of work.

When finished with the server side proxy page we can consider to use javascript in the page where you need to do the changes like:
add a button to validate dynamically if two values entered by the end user are corrects by calling the web service.
Because I cannot have tons of knowledge and because i need to speed up with a good and flexible solution i prefer to use
javascript and jquery library to create a simple script to add to the interested page lines of code like the following one:

`.......
    some globals and locals.....
    ......
    function wsCall(callback) {
        var IDVal = _idAzioneObj.val().trim();
        if ((wsCallCanStart == false) || ((typeof callback !== 'function') && (IDVal.length == 0))) {
            return;    // when waiting for ajax to complete or when called from the save button and the input field is empty.....nothing to do
        }
        if ((typeof callback === 'function') && (IDVal.length == 0)) {
            callback(); // on save click and input field null......continue with normal flow
            return;
        }
        wsCallCanStart = false;
        jQuery('').css('cursor', 'progress');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:     'POST',
            url:      wsProxyPage,
            async:    true,
            data:     {
                          ID          : _idAzioneObj.val(),
                          CODE        : codiceCorso,
                          wsEndPoint  : wsEndPoint,
                          wsNAME      : wsName
                      },
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var retValObj = jQuery(data).find('input[name="retVal"]');
            if (retValObj.length > 0) {
                var retValJson = null;
                try {
                    retValJson = jQuery.parseJSON(retValObj.val());
                } catch (e) {
                    retValJson = null;
                }
                if (retValJson != null) {
                    try {
                        var check   = retValJson.check;
                        var retval1 = retValJson.retval1;
                        var retval2 = retValJson.retval2;
                        var retval3 = retValJson.retval3;
                        if (check < 0 || check > 6) {
                            check = 6;
                        }
                        if (check == 1) {
                            // all ok: use new variables....
                            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                                callback();  // continue with nornal flow
                                return;
                            } else {
                                displayMsg(RetMsg[check]);  // display message to user
                            }
                        } else {
                            displayMsg(RetMsg[check]);
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        displayMsg(genericErrorMsg);
                    }
                } else {
                    displayMsg(err, retValObj.val());
                }
            } else {
                displayMsg(genericErrorMsg);
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            displayMsg(genericErrorMsg);
        }).always(function() {
            wsCallCanStart = true;
            jQuery('').css('cursor', 'auto');
        });
    };`

```
......
some other code
.....

jQuery(function() {
    _idAzioneObj = jQuery('input[name="localname"]');

    if (_idAzioneObj.is(':not([type=hidden])')) {
        _idAzioneObj.after('<a class="sbWDKButton" href="javascript:void(\'check\')" onclick="wsCall(null);return false;" title="' + btnWcTitle + '"><span class="sbDummy">' + btnWcTitle + '</span></a>');
        var SaveObj = jQuery('a[href="javascript:void(\'save\')"]');
        var saveOnClickFuncStr = SaveObj.attr('onclick');
        SaveObj.attr('onclick', 'wsCall(function(){' + saveOnClickFuncStr + '});return false;');
    }
});
```

In this way I overcome the lack of knowledge on the server side simply using javascript and the promise technique: 
If end user clicks the validate button the ws is called via proxy page otherwise the same actions happens and if the ws answered ok the rest of flow can be executed as normally
without any knowledge on Saba.

That's all guys